# Tensorflow training error

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm trying to run faster_rcnn on another dataset based on pascal VOC format. But this is how the training turns out to be like:

[image: warning and NAN losses]

After a warning as below the loss values all go to **nan**:

> proposal_layer_tf.py:150: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater_equal keep =
> np.where((ws >= min_size) & (hs >= min_size))[0]

#### This is proposal_layer_tf.py line 146-151:

```
def _filter_boxes(boxes, min_size):
    """Remove all boxes with any side smaller than min_size."""
    ws = boxes[:, 2] - boxes[:, 0] + 1
    hs = boxes[:, 3] - boxes[:, 1] + 1
    keep = np.where((ws >= min_size) & (hs >= min_size))[0]
return keep
```

As you see, the total loss value is changing in a weird way and after the warning it becomes nan. What can I do to make it right?

(gpu: Geforce 940m)

Comment: Try reduce your learning rate.

Comment: I reduced learning rate from **0.001** to **0.0001** and still got the same result.

Comment: reducing learning rate to 0.00001 also didn't help.

Comment: I have the exact same issue as you right now. Changing the learning rates did not help. What size are you input images? Anyways let me know if you figure it out and I'll let you know if I figure it out :P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely caused by your annotations. In the Faster-RCNN implementation, when they load the bounding boxes into a data frame, they subtract the coordinates `x1,y1,x2,y2` by `1` to make it 0-based. In my case, I created my own xml annotations and they were already 0-based. Thus, if I ran the default Faster-RCNN implementation, subtracting `1` from `0` would cause an underflow error. So removing that subtraction fixed my problem.

You can remove the subtraction in `pascal_voc.py` or edit your annotations to make them 1-based. If you choose to edit the `pascal_voc.py` file go here:

```
def _load_pascal_annotation(self, index):

    # ...
    # ...
    # ...

    # Load object bounding boxes into a data frame.
    for ix, obj in enumerate(objs):
        bbox = obj.find('bndbox')
        # Make pixel indexes 0-based
        x1 = float(bbox.find('xmin').text) #- 1 <- comment these out
        y1 = float(bbox.find('ymin').text) #- 1
        x2 = float(bbox.find('xmax').text) #- 1
        y2 = float(bbox.find('ymax').text) #- 1

    # ...
    # ...
    # ...
```

Comment: It turned out this is right. I printed each image name on each loop to see which annotation file has the problem. It was some files with truncated objects which had coordinates greater or less than image size. For example there were objects with x_max = 1033 while my images are of size 1024*1024. I removed those objects.